# QTP is not recognising Java objects

Tags: qtp

I have a java application which is running in a browser which seems to be invisible to QTP.

*I've not automated for a Java application before so I'm not sure what to expect, but I'd expect more than this.*

When I use object spy I see one object present (well, three counting the path to the object of interest), 
`Browser(...).Page(...).WinObject("nativeclass:=SunAwtCanvas")` which I can do nothing with.

I cannot interact or see any other objects. What do I need to do?

Comment: One of the benefits of commercial testing tools is the support provided by the vendors. I suggest that you raise this with HP.

Answer (score 2):

You must use Java Add-in for QTP to recognize the java objects.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not working in QTP, check which version of Java you are using. After that check the support QTP gives for different versions. It happened to me once, and I degraded my machine to Java 1.6. So it can be one of the issue!